# Why was Ahok convicted of blasphemy when so many similar cases are around?

Tags: blasphemy

Ahok said that people may be lied to by using Al Maidah 51.

[Why is Ahok in prison? A legal analysis of the decision](http://indonesiaatmelbourne.unimelb.edu.au/why-is-ahok-in-prison-a-legal-analysis-of-the-decision/)

The court effectively says that Ahok speech implies that the Quran is a tool for lying.

The problem is, is there a guarantee that anyone that is using religion isn't lying?

To the opposite.

We have many cases where people use the religious textbook for many fraudulent aims.

Heres an article about a Quran corruption case in Indonesia, called [KPK Questions Witness of Quran Procurement Corruption](https://en.tempo.co/read/news/2017/05/10/055874217/KPK-Questions-Witness-of-Quran-Procurement-Corruption)

Abu Tours and First travel using Umrah (a Muslim pilgrimage) case, to defraud people.

[Another Umrah scam](http://www.en.netralnews.com/news/currentnews/read/20211/another.umrah.scam..hundreds.of.prospective.pilgrims.of.abu.tours.report.to.bareskrim)

[Trial starts for alleged 'umrah' fraud case](http://www.thejakartapost.com/news/2018/02/19/trial-starts-for-alleged-umrah-fraud-case.html)

So clearly here, religions have been used for a dishonest purpose.

Yet almost 0 Muslims complain about Abu Tour. Many newspapers tell about people using the Quran to commit corruption. No body-mind. We sort of knew it happens. Duh...

Yet, when Ahok said that people are using the Quran to lie, somehow it's a big deal. Most politicians lie or mislead. It's politics. C'mon.

Why is Ahok case such a big deal from the law perspective?

Answer (score 2):

Because law is not independent of politics - particularly in Indonesia.

Comment: That would be a good answer. I need details.

Comment: @SharenEayrs This answer, while simple, is fundamentally the correct one. Prosecutors have broad discretion to decide when to press charges given limited resources. It is impossible to prosecute every violation of the law. And, prosecutors are, directly or indirectly, accountable to politicians and the public. If politicians and the public care, they care. If politicians and the public don't care, they don't. The Ahok case isn't necessarily a big deal from a law perspective, but because politicians and the public care about it, the prosecutor is using all tool available to him to act.